# Popup not working and data is not visible in the html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, sqlite, flask

I am trying to make a simple game like Dino Runner from Chrome. I want to have a popup in the beginning of the game, where the player should put his name to start the game. When I put the popup then, either the submit button doesn't work (the popup doesn't vanishes) and the game can't be played, even though the popup vanishes in some way, I am unable to start the game. I am so tired as I have tried this for a whole day. Even if I put the values in the popup, the name is not saved in the database, nor is the sccore. So it can't be displayed to the website.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/google/stagehand">
    <title>Run Naruto Run</title>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css')}}">

    <!-- Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/fire.js') }}" type="module"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/naruto.js') }}" type="module"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}" type="module"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/property.js') }}" type="module"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/forest.js') }}" type="module"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay" data-blur></div>
<!-- Pop Up Container -->
<div class="popup-container" id="popupContainer" data-popup>
    <h2>ENTER YOUR NAME</h2>
    <label>
        <input type="text" class="player-name" id="playerName" placeholder="NAME" required data-player-name>
    </label>
    <br>
    <button class="submit-button" id="submitButton" data-button>Let's Play</button>
</div>

<!-- Game Container -->
<div class="game-container" id="gameContainer" data-game>
    <div class="world" data-world>
        <div class="score-track">
            <div class="score">Score</div>
            <div class="point" data-score>0</div>
        </div>
        <h1 class="start-text" data-start-text>Press "SPACE" To Jump</h1>
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/background.png')}}" class="forest" data-forest>
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/background.png')}}" class="forest" data-forest>
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/start-position.png')}}" class="naruto" data-naruto>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Leaderboard Container-->
<div class="high-score" id="highScore">
    <h1>LEADERBOARD</h1>
    <table class="score-table">
        <tr>
            <th class="scorer-name">Name of Player</th>
            <th class="scorer-class">Highest Score</th>
        </tr>
        {% for highscore in highscores %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ highscore[1] }}</td>
            <td>{{ highscore[2] }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffefd5;
    z-index: -5;
}

.overlay{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    z-index: 5;
}

.popup-container{
    display: none;
    background: burlywood;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 4vmin 9vmin;
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1vmin solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}

.player-name{
    border-radius: 5vmin;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1vmin 5vmin;
    font-weight: revert;
}

.submit-button{
    padding: 1vmin;
    margin-top: 2vmin;
    background: #6a8e1c;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 1vmin;
}

.submit-button:hover{
    font-weight: bolder;
    background: #3b5404;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.game-container {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    width: 90vw;
    border: 1vmin solid black;
    border-radius: 1vmin;
}

.world {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.score-track {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 3vmin;
    right: 1vmin;
    top: 1vmin;
    z-index: 1;
}

.start-text {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 5vmin;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.forest {
    --left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 1%);
    z-index: -1;
}

.naruto {
    --bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1%;
    height: 30%;
    bottom: calc(var(--bottom) * 1%);
}

.fire {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 1%);
    height: 25%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.high-score {
    color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
}

.score-table{
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Styling the table header */
th {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Styling alternating rows */
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Styling on hover */
tr:hover {
    background-color: #bee0e7;
}

/* Adding borders to cells */
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid #daecef;
}

/* Centering text in cells */
th,
td {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Adding spacing between cells */
td {
    padding: 15px;
}

/* Centering the heading */
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Styling the highscore container */
#highscore {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 600px;
}
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, session
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "tH1$iz@$3cRetK€y"

DATABASE = 'instance/leaderboard.db'


def create_table():
    connection = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS highscores
                        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                        username TEXT, score INTEGER)
                    ''')
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    create_table()
    connection = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC')
    highscores = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    return render_template('index.html', highscores=highscores)


@app.route('/submit_score', methods=['POST'])
def submit_score():
    name = request.form.get('username')
    new_score = int(request.form.get('score'))

    connection = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Get the existing score for the username
    cursor.execute('SELECT score FROM highscores WHERE username = ?', (name,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    if result is None:
        # Insert a new record if username not found
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO highscores (username, score) VALUES (?, ?)', (name, new_score))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        return jsonify({"message": "Score submitted successfully"})

    existing_score = result[0]

    # Update if new score is greater than the existing score
    if new_score > existing_score:
        cursor.execute('UPDATE highscores SET score = ? WHERE username = ?', (new_score, name))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        return jsonify({"message": "Score updated successfully"})

    connection.close()
    return jsonify({"message": "Score not updated as it's not higher"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

script.js:

```
import {setupForest, updateForest} from './forest.js';
import {setupCharacter, updateCharacter, getCharacterRects, setGameOver} from './naruto.js';
import {setupFire, updateFire, getFireRects} from './fire.js';

const WORLD_WIDTH = 100;
const WORLD_HEIGHT = 30;
const SPEED_SCALE_INCREASE = 0.00001;

const worldElem = document.querySelector("[data-world]");
const scoreElem = document.querySelector("[data-score]");
const startScreenElem = document.querySelector("[data-start-text]");

const overlayElem = document.getElementById("overlay");
const popUpContainer = document.getElementById("popupContainer");
const submitName = document.getElementById("submitButton");
var gameContainer = document.getElementById("gameContainer")


let lastTime
let speedScale
let score
let current_player
let isGameRunning = false

popUpContainer.style.display = "block";
overlayElem.style.display = "block";

setPixelToWorldScale()
window.addEventListener("resize", setPixelToWorldScale)
document.addEventListener("keydown", handleStart)
setupForest()

function update(time) {
    if (lastTime == null) {
        lastTime = time
        window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
        return
    }
    const delta = time - lastTime

    updateForest(delta, speedScale)
    updateCharacter(delta, speedScale)
    updateFire(delta, speedScale)
    updateSpeedScale(delta)
    updateScore(delta)
    if (checkLose()) return handleLose()

    lastTime = time
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

function checkLose() {
    const characterRects = getCharacterRects()
    return getFireRects().some(rect => isCollision(rect, characterRects))
}

function isCollision(rect1, rect2) {
    return (
        rect1.left < rect2.right &&
        rect1.top < rect2.bottom &&
        rect1.right > rect2.left &&
        rect1.bottom > rect2.top
    )
}

function updateSpeedScale(delta) {
    speedScale += delta * SPEED_SCALE_INCREASE
}

function updateScore(delta) {
    score += delta * 0.01
    scoreElem.textContent = Math.floor(score)
}

function handleStart(event) {
    if (!isGameRunning && event.code === "Space") {
        isGameRunning = true;
        lastTime = null
        score = 0
        speedScale = 1
        current_player = null;

        setupForest()
        setupCharacter()
        setupFire()
        startScreenElem.classList.add("hide")
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleStart);
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleSubmit);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
    }
}

function handleLose() {
    if (isGameRunning) {
        isGameRunning = false;
        setGameOver()
        submitScore(current_player, score)
        refreshTable()
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.addEventListener("keydown", handleStart)
            startScreenElem.classList.remove("hide")
        }, 500)
    }
}

function handleSubmit() {
        const playerName = value;

        if (playerName.trim() === "") {
            alert("PLEASE ENTER A NAME TO BEGIN PLAYING!.")
        } else {
            current_player = playerName;
            popUpContainer.style.display = "none";
            overlayElem.style.display = "none";
            isGameRunning = false;
            document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleStart)
            document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleSubmit);
        }
}

function submitScore(player, point) {
    const url = '/submit_score';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('playerName', player)
    formData.append('score', point)

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Score is successfully submitted.');
        } else {
            console.error('Score could not be submitted');
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error("Error submitting the score.");
    });
}

function refreshTable() {
    fetch('/').then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
            const newTable = doc.querySelector('#highscore');
            const oldTable = document.querySelector('#highscore');
            oldTable.parentNode.replaceChild(newTable, oldTable);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error refreshing table:', error);
        });
}

function setPixelToWorldScale() {
    let worldToPixelScale
    if (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight < WORLD_WIDTH / WORLD_HEIGHT) {
        worldToPixelScale = window.innerWidth / WORLD_WIDTH
    } else {
        worldToPixelScale = window.innerHeight / WORLD_HEIGHT
    }

    worldElem.style.width = `${WORLD_WIDTH * worldToPixelScale}px`
    worldElem.style.height = `${WORLD_HEIGHT * worldToPixelScale}px`
}
```

I have tried it in several ways, to solve it in different ways, let it be by putting in css or creating a new function for it. But still, I am niether able to save the data, nor am I able to remove the popup successfully and play the game.

Comment: Please narrow your code down to a [mre].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).